# scanning a nested list with a regular positive lookbehind

Tags: python, regex

Id like to post a question regarding nested lists.

```
import re
string = '[5, 42, [19, 3, 5, [7, 7, 5]], 42, 3.14, [6,6,6,7], 2,71, 0,0]'


m = re.findall(r'(?<=\])\]', string)

print(m)
print(len(m))
```

Im trying to write a piece of code which would tell me how many "levels" the list has. In order to do that i want to make the expression match every time 2 square brackets are one after the other. However I have to specify how many characters the lookbehind should go back. This is not very useful since id like to make this work for any given string and 
"(?<=]*)]" 
would not work.
Can anyone suggest a workaround this problem ?

Comment: So what's you're expected output in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Using [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) and recursion:

```
>>> depth = lambda l: 1 + max(depth(x) for x in l) if type(l) is list else 0
>>> depth(eval(strng))
3
```

Comment: elegant and simple, +1.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` will play better here

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution that will count nested levels:

```
strng = '[5, 42, [19, 3, 5, [7, 7, 5]], 42, 3.14, [6,6,6,7], 2,71, 0,0]'
level = 0
cnt = 0
for c in strng:
    if c == '[':
        cnt+=1
    elif c == ']':
        cnt-=1
        if cnt > 0:
            level+=1
print (level)
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/m0C5MM). Result: `3`.

Comment: ok yes, that is a lot more simple than my idea. Thank you , i will try that out right away !